# Specifying per-repository proxy for Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, proxy

I have a problem specifying per-repository proxy for Mercurial.

If I specify proxy on command-line, everything works:

```
hg pull --config http_proxy.host=proxyhost:3128
```

If I specify proxy in ~/.hgrc, everything works too. Contents of ~/.hgrc:

```
[http_proxy]
host=proxyhost:3128
```

But if I put that section into .hg/hgrc of local repository, proxy does not work:

```
user@NOTE:~/Project$ cat .hg/hgrc 
[http_proxy]
host=proxyhost:3128

[paths]
default=http://repohost/Project/
user@NOTE:~/Project$ hg pull --debug
using http://repohost/Project/
sending between command
abort: error: Name or service not known
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a bug to me.  I can see how it would happen too, though it confuses me a bit that the command line `--config` option works and the repository-level config doesn't.  But not too much.

Comment: Yeah, 1.7.0 installed from Mercurial site works fine. Version 1.4.3 from Ubuntu does not.